# Mongoose _id of type String not throwing error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema in Mongoose:

```
const member = new Schema({
  _id: { type: String, required: true },
  ...
});
```

but when I use `await MemberModel.findOne({ _id: req.params.userID });` in an express request handler, I get a `CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "MY_SECRET_VALUE" at path "_id" for model "Member".`

As you can see, I have set `_id`'s type to `String` in the Schema - why is it not allowing me to search for the _id by a String value?

Comment: You need `{ _id: false }` in the "schema options" ( the second argument to the `Schema` function ). Without it, mongoose will still attempt to use it's "built in" methods for validating input for `_id`, which of course it expects to an `ObjectId` by default.

Comment: Thank you - the first answer on the duplicate doesn't say that this is necessary as far as I understand.

Comment: Well the "first" or even accepted one is not necessarily the correct one ( and in due fairness, the API has changed a bit since the "first" answer was written ). Other answers there do say this is necessary, but *may not* embellish as to why. Hence the comment from myself to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but to get the id in mongoose

you have to make the type equal to `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`

```
type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was asked. A non-ObjectId value needs to be stored in _id, therefore `type` is a `String`